# I use many "OR" operator how can i refactor code in JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to refactor my code. That have many "OR" operator
what should i do ?

```
        public boolean validateRequireField(JSONObject tradeDeal){
        boolean status = true;

        if (!tradeDeal.has("Symbol") || !tradeDeal.has("Deal") || !tradeDeal.has("Position")) {
            status = false;
        } else if (tradeDeal.get("Symbol").equals("") || tradeDeal.get("Deal").equals("")
                || tradeDeal.get("Position").equals("")) {
            status = false;
        }

        return status;
 }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question about codereview should asked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: I'm sorry i just want to refact and Thank you to guide me post this at Code Review (I'm don't know this before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something along those lines

```
public boolean validateRequireField(JSONObject tradeDeal){
    
    if(!tradeDeal.has("Symbol")  || tradeDeal.get("Symbol").equals("") ) {
        return false;
    }
    if(!tradeDeal.has("Deal")  || tradeDeal.get("Deal").equals("") ) {
        return false;
    }
    if(!tradeDeal.has("Position")  || tradeDeal.get("Position").equals("") ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```